# how to implement screen in react native/expo for a large number of products with different number of weights and prices

Tags: expo, react-native, react-native-ios

how to implement screen in react native for a large number of products of a retailer store where each product will have different number of weights and prices.
Consider the products as

```
[product A : "name", "image", "description", [attributes:"100gm"-"10/-","200gm"-"20/-"]]; [product B : "name", "image", "description", [attributes:"100gm"-"20/-","400gm"-"20/-"]];[product C : "name", "image", "description", [attributes:"1000gm"-"100/-","500gm"-"50/-","250gm"-"25/-"]];
```

Like this up-to some N number of products.

Comment: Are you asking someone to design a screen for you?

Comment: Not exactly. Anyway I completed this. If you want clarity on how I did this, ask me, I'll post it for you.